# Reusing query/subquery results to assign multiple outputs depending on a column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to assign 4 output values based on specific status of a column, while counting how many occurrences of it there are.

For example

```
   Select @someVariable =(Select count(*) as r
    from table 
    join table 2 as t2
    on r.id= t2.id 
    where getdate() between t2.start and t2.end )
```

adding extra where statement such as and `t2.status="somestatus"` works, but this way I have to to same query for eachdifferent status I have, is it possible to reuse that query or somehow sub query assignment of output variables based on `t2.status`

Just in case my code example is bit messed up (just writing some from memory), what I am trying to do, is count how many columns there are with particular status and fits in time frame.

I've done what I need, by having multiple queries like this in stored procedure, but I don't want to keep it this way.

Comment: Do you want a row for each status / count or a column for each with the column name corresponding to the status?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the data you'd like to see?

Comment: @JoeC I just want the count of number of rows with a status that equals to whatever I input, I don't want group by, I've already done that, some of the statuses needs to be added ( as a count, say status 1 count + status 2 count) .

Comment: @Luke101 sure 
`@ var1 = 55 ( count of rows with status of 1 +2 )
 @var2=33 (count of rows with status of 3)
@var3= 40 ( count of rows with status of 4) etc `
There are extra where statements such as where current date falls between timestamps in database (Start/finish). I just want to be able assign multiple variables to my query that get's all rows within period of time and then count each status number and assign to output variable, groupby is not suitable for me as that results in a lot of hassle to processing data later, which is uglier than multiple sub queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the query as a single `select`:

```
Select @someVariable = count(*)
from table join
     table 2 as t2
     on r.id = t2.id 
where getdate() between t2.start and t2.end;
```

You can then add more variables easily:

```
Select @someVariable = count(*),
       @someVariable2 = sum(case when t2.status = 'somestatus' then 1 else 0 end)
from table join
     table 2 as t2
     on r.id = t2.id 
where getdate() between t2.start and t2.end;
```

Comment: could you explain how `sum(case when t2.status = 'somestatus' then 1 else 0 end)` works in more detail, especially its ending

Comment: @AistisTaraskevicius . . . This is called conditional aggregation.  It counts the number of rows where `t2.status = 'somestatus'`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
SELECT 
    @TotalCount = count(*), 
    @Status1 = s1.status1, 
    @Status2 = s2.status2, 
    @Status3 = s3.status3 
FROM [table]
CROSS JOIN (SELECT count(*) as status1 FROM [table] WHERE [status] = 'status1' and getdate() between [start] and [end]) s1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT count(*) as status2 FROM [table] WHERE [status] = 'status2' and getdate() between [start] and [end]) s2
CROSS JOIN (SELECT count(*) as status3 FROM [table] WHERE [status] = 'status3' and getdate() between [start] and [end]) s3
```

The results will output to variables using one query.

Comment: While this gets nice to look at result, its not suitable for me, as I want to be able to add count of some statuses and I would rather not create another class to just reprocess results to do that and figure out what status 1 means in the code, returning @Scheduled = 50 is much easier to use and maintain, than returning 2 row with 2 columns with 2 statuses  and 2 numbers that represent scheduled

Comment: it doesnt seem to actually join second table which holds status and would it be possible join second table and perform date check and only then use those results to calculate counts based on status

Comment: Actually, I think Gordon has the most elegant answer. After I figured what you want I see Gordon solution is better.. In his solution just add the other conditions then you would have a functioning query.